# Deserialize XML. Catch errors?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I've have the following deserialization function (code snippet) to convert XML to Object. However, I need to catch errors and it seems to be failing silently. I'd like to know when there's a XML to object mismatch. It's not throwing any errors or exception, it's simply omitting the value. XmlDeserializationEvents e exists but is full of null values.

```
   string Str_Response = Utilities.PostToURL(URL, XML_Request);

   TextReader Txt_Reader = new StringReader(Str_Response);

   XmlReaderSettings XML_Settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

   XmlReader Xml_Reader = XmlReader.Create(Txt_Reader, XML_Settings, (string)null);

   var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UPS.TrackResponse));

   XmlDeserializationEvents e = new XmlDeserializationEvents();

   UPS.TrackResponse Response = (UPS.TrackResponse)deserializer.Deserialize(Xml_Reader, e);
```

Comment: Just reading the documentation, I would guess you need to add event handlers to `XmlDeserializationEvents` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmldeserializationevents?view=netframework-4.7.2 

You could also omit the events argument and do a try/catch with `InvalidOperationException` and look at it that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to ryzngard who let me know that all I need to do is add event handlers to the XmlDeserializationEvents like so:

```
XmlDeserializationEvents e = new XmlDeserializationEvents();

   e.OnUnknownAttribute += On_UnknownAttribute;
   e.OnUnknownElement += On_UnknownElement;
   e.OnUnknownNode += On_UnknownNode;
   e.OnUnreferencedObject += On_UnreferencedObject;
```

And the relevant handlers stubs:

```
  public static void On_UnknownAttribute(object sender, XmlAttributeEventArgs e)
  {
  }

  public static void On_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
  {
  }

  public static void On_UnknownNode(object sender, XmlNodeEventArgs e)
  {
  }

  public static void On_UnreferencedObject(object sender, UnreferencedObjectEventArgs e)
  {
  }
```

The MSDN docs don't spell this out very well so I hope this helps someone in the future.